# Getting readAddress() exception on Webclient while connecting to Okta

Tags: spring, exception, webclient

I ma getting the below error while connecting  to  okta. It is observed that every time the connection is idle for a very long time this Exception occurs. Has anyone  experienced  it before, how can this be resolved?

Caused by: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Operation timed out

```
Spring Version: 2.1.9
Project Reactor - 1.0.1 release
Java version : 1.8
Application is deployed in azure kubernates cluster in a docker container.
```